# How to decode MappedByteBuffer without copying in Java

Tags: java

How can I decode the UTF-8 codepoints of a `MappedByteBuffer` in Java without copying the buffer? Copying the buffer into memory would defeat the point of mapping the memory, and since `CharsetDecoder` would require me to copy the buffer with the `toCharArray` method, it would defeat the purpose of mapping the memory. Is there any way to efficiently decode it without copying the buffer?

Comment: You can use decode on a `MappedByteBuffer buffer`, i.e. `CharBuffer cb = UTF_8.decode(buffer);`

Comment: The closest thing I can find is `ByteBuffer#asCharBuffer()`, which states the returned `CharBuffer` is only a view over the `ByteBuffer`. I assume it works the same for `MappedByteBuffer` (no mention of behavior changing in the latter's documentation). But I can't seem to find any information regarding **how** it decodes the underlying bytes into characters. Which encoding is used? Is that configurable?

Comment: @Slaw I thought that just gave a UTF-16 view of the bytes, but I agree it's unclear.

Comment: @tgdavies Looking at the source code, it looks like it allocates a separate (non-direct) `CharBuffer`.

Comment: `decode` certainly does.

Comment: @tgdavies Oh, sorry. Was [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72843632/how-to-decode-mappedbytebuffer-without-copying-in-java#comment128662843_72843632) responding to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72843632/how-to-decode-mappedbytebuffer-without-copying-in-java#comment128662809_72843632), or the comment I have since deleted asking if `decode` returns a view or a copy?

Comment: @Slaw I think `asCharBuffer` doesn't decode UTF-8, but just gives a view of the `ByteBuffer` as 16 bit values. I agree that `decode` returns a new `CharBuffer`

Comment: *Is there any way to efficiently decode it without copying the buffer?* You're not telling us the [goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions). For instance if you knew where the codepoints lie and your goal were to show them in your gui, then the answer would be to go to the correct elements and decode the value without copying

Comment: My goal is to create a Lexer as I am trying to implement an interpreter that supports full Unciode.

Comment: Please see than answer I posted. No copy of the `byte[]` occurs. What does happen is a new `char[]` is allocated.
That is unavoidable: the UTF-8 `CharsetDecoder` returns a `CharBuffer` (which is backed by a `char[]`).
Be aware that the length of that backing `char[]` will be equal to the number of Bytes available (`remaining()`) in your `MappedByteBuffer`.
For multi-byte Unicode content, the number of actual chars will be less than the number of bytes, so use the relevant `CharBuffer` methods to access the result
(`charBuffer.position()`, `charBuffer.length()`, `charBuffer.toString()`).

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, there is no way (without manually decoding) to decode the UTF-8 codepoints without loading the file into memory, right?

Comment: I think the UTF-8 CharsetDecoder does it about as well as it can be done. It uses your MappedByteBuffer without cloning it (or the backing byte[]). It creates a CharBuffer result (backed by a char[]) & that has to be done because you're converting from Bytes to Chars. You could get slight performance gains by reusing objects as I mentioned in my Answer, but then you have to do everything yourself, which requires detailed knowledge of Charsets, is complicated and error-prone.  And there's still no way around that new char[] whatever you do.

Comment: Ok, so in terms of the memory usage if I have a say 200 megabyte file, I would have to buffer all 200 megabytes into memory, right?

Comment: Where are the data coming from? A File? Is the MappedByteBuffer an absolute requirement? Would some InputStream do instead? I'm trying out an idea. Watch this space...

Comment: Yes, the input data is coming from a file. The only reason I was trying to use a MapepdByteBuffer is that in cases of massive files I wouldn't have to buffer the files in memory and rather use the virtual memory in a fashion similar to `mmap` in C.

Comment: @ishaangupte Sorry this took so long, I was feeling a bit under-the-weather yesterday. I've posted the code as a new Answer. If you like it, you could give it your vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a somewhat more complete answer.

It reads the Input-File in Chunks & stores the result in a `CharBuffer`.

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CoderResult;
import java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException;
import java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class ChunkedUtf8Decoder {
    /*
     * Valid UTF-8 Multi-Bytes
     * -----------------------
     * 1-Byte : 0xxxxxxx
     * 2-Byte : 110xxxxx + 10xxxxxx
     * 3-Byte : 1110xxxx + 10xxxxxx + 10xxxxxx
     * 4-Byte : 11110xxx + 10xxxxxx + 10xxxxxx + 10xxxxxx
     */
    private static final int            UTF8_CONTINUE_MASK   = 0b11_000000;
    private static final int            UTF8_INVALID_MASK    = 0b11111_000;

    private static final int            UTF8_CONTINUE_PREFIX = 0b10_000000;
    private static final int            UTF8_INVALID_PREFIX  = UTF8_INVALID_MASK;

    private static final int            CHUNK_SIZE           = 24; // TODO Test value! Try something larger, e.g. 64_000

    private        final CharsetDecoder utf8Decoder          = UTF_8.newDecoder();
    private        final ByteBuffer     bb                   = ByteBuffer.allocate(CHUNK_SIZE); // TODO maybe allocateDirect?
    private        final CharBuffer     cb;
    private        final Path           inputPath;

    private              byte[]         remainder            = {};
    private              int            bytesChunked         = 0;

    public ChunkedUtf8Decoder(final Path inputPath) throws IOException {

        this.inputPath = inputPath;
        this.cb        = CharBuffer.allocate(Math.toIntExact(Files.size(inputPath)));

//      this.utf8Decoder.onMalformedInput     (CodingErrorAction.REPLACE); // (TODO Default is REPORT)
//      this.utf8Decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE); // (TODO Default is REPORT)
    }

    /**
     * Split the Input-File into Chunks & Decode them, appending the result to our CharBuffer.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void decode() throws IOException {

        try(final FileChannel  channel = FileChannel.open(inputPath))
        {
            while (channel.read(bb) != -1) {

                debugBytesIn("Read......:", false);

                this.remainder    =  backupToCharBoundary();

                debugBytesIn("Backed up.:", true);

                this.bytesChunked += decodeChunk();

                bb.clear();             // (position=0, limit=capacity, mark=-1)
                bb.put(this.remainder); // (Final Remainder is dealt with below)
            }
            debugBytesIn("EOF.......:", false);
            /*
             * Lastly, deal with Final Remainder (0 to 4 Bytes) @ start of Buffer...
             */
            decodeChunk();
        }
    }

    /**
     * We try to back up the BB to a Character boundary.
     * If the file is correctly encoded, the shorter BB will then decode OK.
     * The Remainder will be processed after the NEXT Read operation.
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws MalformedInputException
     */
    private byte[] backupToCharBoundary() throws MalformedInputException {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

            final int trailingBytePos = bb.position() - i;

            if (trailingBytePos < 0) {
                /*
                 *  If there were too few Bytes available, carry them over until either
                 *  a) more Bytes become available, or
                 *  b) EOF is reached
                 */
                final byte[] remainder = new byte[bb.position()];

                bb.get  (0,  remainder);
                bb.clear();       // (position=0, limit=capacity, mark=-1)

                return remainder; // (Entire contents of BB in Remainder, BB Empty)
            }

            final int trailingByte = 0xFF & bb.get(trailingBytePos);

            /*
             * We stop as soon as we encounter a Character-Selector...
             * (The following 2 intervals are either invalid or a continuation-character)
             */
            if ((trailingByte  &  UTF8_INVALID_MASK )  !=  UTF8_INVALID_PREFIX     // 11111xxx
            &&  (trailingByte  &  UTF8_CONTINUE_MASK)  !=  UTF8_CONTINUE_PREFIX) { // 10xxxxxx
                /*
                 *  OK, we have found a (1-, 2-, 3- or 4-Byte) Character-Selector...
                 */
                final byte[] remainder = new byte[i];

                bb.get     (trailingBytePos, remainder);
                bb.position(trailingBytePos);

                return remainder; // (Trailing 1-4 Bytes of BB in Remainder)
            }
        }
        /*
         * Although at least 4 Bytes are available, We couldn't find a Character-Selector!
         * This is an error.
         * We leave the ByteBuffer unchanged & return an empty Remainder.
         * The CharsetDecoder will produce a MalformedInputException in due course...
         */
        return new byte[0];
    }

    /**
     * Decode the current Chunk of Bytes & append the result to our CB.
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws CharacterCodingException
     */
    private int decodeChunk() throws CharacterCodingException {
        try {
            this.bb.flip(); // (limit=position, position=0, mark=-1)

            ;                       this.utf8Decoder.reset();
            final CoderResult res = this.utf8Decoder.decode(this.bb, this.cb, true);

            System.out.println("CB Chars..: " + this.cb.position());
            /*
             * Why on earth is UNDERFLOW the correct result of an error-free Decode?!
             */
            if (res.isUnderflow() == false) {
                res.throwException();
            }
            return this.bb.position();
        }
        catch (final  MalformedInputException e) {
            throw new MalformedInputException     (this.bytesChunked + e.getInputLength());
        }
        catch (final  UnmappableCharacterException e) {
            throw new UnmappableCharacterException(this.bytesChunked + e.getInputLength());
            /*
             * (Famous Last Words "UnmappableCharacterException never occurs with UTF-8 Decoder")
             */
        }
        catch (final CharacterCodingException inputUnderflowOrOutputOverflow) {
            throw                             inputUnderflowOrOutputOverflow;
            /*
             * (Underflow if the final Character of the final Chunk was incomplete)
             * (Overflow  if the Output Buffer is too small, which SHOULD NOT HAPPEN with our big CB)
             */
        }
    }

    /**
     * Some Debug Writes.
     * 
     * @param debugText
     * @param includeRemainder
     */
    private void debugBytesIn(final String debugText, final boolean includeRemainder) {

        System        .out.print(debugText + " previous=" + this.bytesChunked + " bbPos=" + bb.position() + " Bytes.:");

        for (    int p = 0; p < bb.position();         p++) {
            System    .out.print(" " + Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bb.get(p)));
        }
        if (includeRemainder) {
            System    .out.print(" Remainder.:");

            for (int r = 0; r < this.remainder.length; r++) {
                System.out.print(" " + Integer.toHexString(0xFF & this.remainder[r]));
            }
        }
        System        .out.println();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        final ChunkedUtf8Decoder utf8Decoder = new ChunkedUtf8Decoder(Path.of("Utf8-Chars_nn.txt"));
        ;                        utf8Decoder.decode();

        System.out.println      (utf8Decoder.cb.flip()); // TODO Note.: flip()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really: essentially a `char[]` needs to be built from the `byte[]` (either direct or indirect) which is backing the MappedByteBuffer.

So something like the following is necessary:

```
private static CharBuffer readUTF8(final Path path) throws IOException {

    final long             byteCount  = path.toFile().length();

    final FileChannel      channel    = FileChannel.open(PATH);
    final MappedByteBuffer byteBuffer = channel.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, byteCount);

    return StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(byteBuffer);
}
```

The following snippet demonstrates the possibility to reuse various components used in the above example.
As stated in the Javadoc, this is a complex matter.
So it should only be considered as a collection of ideas & invocations of various JDK methods, which may or may not be of use, depending on your concrete requirements.
You really need an in-depth understanding of Charsets etc. before using the following...

```
/**
 * It is possible to pre-allocate a CharsetDecoder & CharBuffer & use those multiple times.
 * Be aware that this would make your logic MUCH more complicated.
 * a) you'll have to control use/reuse & initialisation of the CharsetDecoder
 * b) you'll need to ensure the CharBuffer has sufficient capacity
 * 
 * The following is just snippets which may be of use.
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    final CharsetDecoder   utf8Decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
    ;                      utf8Decoder.onMalformedInput     (CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
    ;                      utf8Decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);

    final int              charBufLength    = 0; // TODO how long?
    final CharBuffer       charBuf          = CharBuffer.allocate(charBufLength);

    final int              byteBufferLength = 0; // TODO how long?
    final MappedByteBuffer byteBuffer       = FileChannel.open(Path.of("my File")).map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, byteBufferLength);

    readUTF8(utf8Decoder, byteBuffer, charBuf);
}
private static void readUTF8(final CharsetDecoder utf8Decoder, final MappedByteBuffer byteBuffer, final CharBuffer charBuffer) throws IOException {

    /* Maybe */ utf8Decoder.reset();            // TODO check out the source of the following decode(byteBuffer) method
    /* Maybe */ utf8Decoder.decode(byteBuffer); // TODO check out the source of this method

    utf8Decoder.decode(byteBuffer, charBuffer, true); // reuses utf8Decoder & charBuffer
    charBuffer.flip();
}
```